# Check if exists row else insert accordingly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to check if the database has the row Comment matches according from getComments2.

If there exists such row, proceed with the next data checking else it will execute the insert statement

After I ran this code, it gave me:

1. java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set (When database is empty) or
2. java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set (When database is filled).

Code:

```
String url = "test";
String getComments2 = "test1";
String getTime1 = "test2";
String sqlSelect = "Select comment from predata";
PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);
ResultSet rs =  ps1.executeQuery();

boolean exists = false;
while(!rs.last()||(!exists)) {
    rs.next();
    if(rs.getString("Comment").compareTo(getComments2)==0) {
        exists = true;
    }
    if(!exists||rs ==null) {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into predata (topic,comment,date) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, url);
        ps.setString(2, getComments2);
        ps.setString(3, getTime1);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to modify your `while(!rs.last()||(!exists))` to `while(rs.next())`, for it work!

Comment: You'd be seriously better off by leaving this to the database, either by using `merge` as suggested by Jai, or at least by adding a `where` clause on your select statement to only get relevant records, instead of retrieving all rows and manually filtering them.

Answer (score 1):

`rs.last()` moves the cursor to the last row. Then `rs.next()` moves it past the last row, so `rs.getString("Comment")` throws an exception.

The correct logic should be:

```
boolean exists = false;
while (rs.next() && !exists) {
    if(rs.getString("Comment").equals(getComments2)) {
        exists = true;
    }
}
if (!exists) {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into predata (topic,comment,date) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, url);
    ps.setString(2, getComments2);
    ps.setString(3, getTime1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Hello. I used your above code to test. One thing I realized is, it still insert data into database even though exists is not true causing some of the row being duplicate. So for example on the first run It had inserted 40 rows, subsequent run it will have 43 rows, 45, 47, 49 and so on.

Comment: @Gaming `it still insert data into database even though exists is not true` - it should insert data into the database when exists is **not** true, shouldn't it?

Comment: After figuring it this issues, I tried on another method.
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO predata (comment, topic, date) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?, ?, ?) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT comment FROM predata WHERE comment = ?) LIMIT 1;");

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Merge** in your query itself instead of checking condition in code. Else you can user Insert or Replace in query itself.

Comment: This should have been a comment.